# GAE update cron.xml with maven on app with java modules

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have an gae app which is written in java and is split into two different modules. One of these modules has a cron.xml which was installed on initial deployment. Cron tasks works fine and are executed as expected.

Now my problem is that when I redeploy my app with maven (> mvm appengine:update), if I have made changes to the cron.xml, these changes aren't reflected on the server when deployment is done. I.e it's the old cron.xml that's being used.

If I try to update the cron.xml manually (mvn appengine:cron_update) I get an error:

"Bad argument: The requested action does not support EAR configurations"

Basically my question is how do I update the cron.xml?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Actually no, I did touch cron.xml and redeployed a couple of times, then suddenly my changes took effect. Any changes I've made in cron.xml has worked flawless ever since.

Comment: In my case, I misspelled cron.xml and thats why the cron jobs were not showing up on console. After I fixed that, mvn appengine:update lets me update the cron. Although I have no idea how to make mvn appengine:cron_update work.

Answer (score 1):

Right command for this is

```
mvn appengine:deployCron
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run mvn appengine:cron_update after changed your appengine-maven-plugin from

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
```

taken from [appengine-maven-plugin git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin)

into this one from [Apache-Maven and Appengine description](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#compiling_and_building_your_project)

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
       <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.63</version>
    </plugin>
```

Oh, and you might also need to describe your application and version on the appengine-web.xml according to [this explanation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) using these tags

```
    <application>_your_app_id_</application><!-- unused for Cloud SDK based tooling -->
    <version>alpha-001</version><!-- unused for Cloud SDK based tooling -->
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn appengine:cron_update`command (**not update_cron** as was suggested by the previous answerer) in the folder, where your `pom.xml` sits in.

Here's the related section of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.63</version>
    <configuration>
      <appId>{PUT YOUR APP ID HERE}</appId>
      <version>{PUT YOUR APP VERSION HERE}</version>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And here's what my `cron.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/hello</url>
        <description>test cron</description>
        <schedule>every 6 hours</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```